# How to Handle exceptions occured in jdbc code in servlet class

Tags: exception, servlets, jdbc

> Actually i got sql exception in jdbc code now i want to handle or
>   rethrow it to servlet class and show some user defined msg in the web-IE.

```
    catch (Exception e) 
{
            e.printStackTrace();

}

getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/newconfig.jsp?error=1&message=Error%20either%20Source%or%20Target%20Config%20Details%20worng!").forward(request,response);
```

Comment: Ensure that Your question is correctly asked or not?it is not understandable

Comment: HI khaja thank for quick response,  the scenario mine different with above, In my case exception is occurring while getting the connection object in some jdbc code, im calling that method in the servlet now i want show the error message in the same page with the above code.